# Removing multiple items from powershell variable

Tags: powershell

The following works

```
Remove-Item *.xml, *.thm, *.bbl, *.fff
```

But this does not

```
$cleanExtensions = "*.xml, *.thm, *.bbl, *.fff"

Remove-Item $cleanExtensions
```

How can I let `Remove-Item` accept a variable list of items to remove?

Comment: your list is not a list ... it is a _string_. [*grin*] make it into a list/array/collection and it will work since the cmdlet in question will accept an array of items for that default parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first option you are passing a list, while in the second one you are passing a string

Use the following notation to make your variable a list instead of a string

```
$cleanExtensions = "*.xml" , "*.thm", "*.bbl", "*.fff"
Remove-Item $cleanExtensions
```

Comment: Indeed, but more accurately the "list" is an _array_, namely of type `[object[]]`.